# C#, Lokad.Shared: How to write custom rules to use with Enforce

Tags: c#

I am trying out the [Lokad Shared Libraries](http://abdullin.com/shared-libraries/), and it is looking very interesting and useful. I am able to use for example:

```
Enforce.Arguments(() => arg1, () => arg2);
```

to throw an exception if arg1 or arg2 are null. But I would like to check if an IEnumerable has at least one item. I could use:

```
Enforce.That(someSequence.Count() > 0);
```

but that doesn't create a very useful error message. I have tried to look at the Sample code, etc., to find out how to write, and use, a custom rule. But I just can't seem to figure it out!

I have come this far (or short... to be more exact...):

- I should create a class to collect my rules in.
- I think I need to somehow create a `Lokad.Rules.Rule<T>` delegate?
- Which perhaps need to do something with an IScope, whatever that is....
- And then somehow use that rule with one of the Enforce methods, although I am not quite sure how...

So to sum up, this is what I want to end up with:

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(this IEnumerable<T> subjects)
{
    Enforce.Argument(() => subjects);
    // Somehow in an equally smooth way check that 
    // subjects contains at least one element

    // Do stuff
}
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: I'd never heard of Lokad.Shared before this. +1 for interesting new technology!

Comment: Yeah, I have pretty much just started to use it, but have been following the rss feed of this Rinat Abdullin person. Much interesting stuff there. Like the Express and Reflect classes.

Comment: Same here.  I came across when trying to write a Guard statement that didn't require you to provide the property name.  Really digging this work.

Answer (score 1):

Asked kind of the same question in [a blog post](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/22/better-c-design-contracts-in-lokad-shared-libraries.html?lastPage=true#comment3420518) of [Rinat Abdullin](http://abdullin.com/). Got this answer:

> Here's the simplest implementation with the usages:
>
> ```
>     public static class EnumerableIs
>     {
>         public static void NotEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, IScope scope)
>         {
>             if (!collection.Any())
>             {
>                 scope.Error("Enumerable can't be empty.");
>             }
>             scope.ValidateInScope(collection);
>         }
>     }
>
>     [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
>     public void Test()
>     {
>         IEnumerable<object> t = null;
>         Enforce.Argument(() => t, EnumerableIs.NotEmpty);
>     }
>
>     [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
>     public void Test2()
>     {
>         var t = new int[0];
>         Enforce.Argument(() => t, EnumerableIs.NotEmpty);
>     }
>
>     [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
>     public void Test3()
>     {
>         var t = new[] { new object(), null };
>         Enforce.Argument(() => t, EnumerableIs.NotEmpty);
>     }
> ```

And this actually do work. The test methods throws exceptions with these messages:

> Test1:
>   Object of type 'IEnumerable`1' should not be null.
>   Parameter name: t
>
> Test2:
>   Enumerable can't be empty.
>   Parameter name: t
>
> Test3:
>   Object of type 'Object' should not be null.
>   Parameter name: t.[1](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/22/better-c-design-contracts-in-lokad-shared-libraries.html?lastPage=true#comment3420518)

Not quite sure where Test1 and Test3 got their messages from though... like, where it checked for that in the `NotEmpty<T>` method... so I have asked about that...